# Should items be shufled before insert into dynamoddb with one batch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-data-upload.html) best pratice about inserting largen number items into dynamodb. But what if all my items can be inserted with one batch operation (e.g. no more than 25 items) should I shufle them before insert?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this infrequently, then this shouldn't be an issue as DynamoDB has something called "Burst capacity"

> DynamoDB currently retains up to five minutes (300 seconds) of unused read and write capacity.

Just make sure that you will not exceed this burst capacity, as that will result in your writes being throttled.

However, if you are doing this very frequently, or do not have sufficient burst capacity to cover the call, you should spread out your writes across as many partitions as possible.  As the batch operations documentation states:

> DynamoDB performs the individual read or write operations in parallel

This means that it's subject to the same limitations as normal, single operations.

Comment: The question is not about capacity, but about hot writes. When several wtires go to single dynamodb partition which can be en issue even if capacity is enough

Comment: If a single batch write is causing hot partition issues for you, then you absolutely should be shuffling or queueing these writes to spread them out.  And of course, if this is a particularly frequent task, and something that will scale in the future, it would be wise to rethink your partition key design.